# grep content between two starting bracket

Tags: linux, awk, grep, regular-expression, cut

Below is file output that I want to access

```
[1]
RsyncCommand: 0
Number of files: 18
Number of files transferred: 0
Total file size: 24.01M bytes
Total transferred file size: 0 bytes
Literal data: 0 bytes
Matched data: 0 bytes
File list size: 354
File list generation time: 0.002 seconds
File list transfer time: 0.000 seconds
Total bytes sent: 424
Total bytes received: 69
total size is 24.01M  speedup is 48701.73 (DRY RUN)


[2]
RsyncCommand: 0
Number of files: 21
Number of files transferred: 0
Total file size: 5.22M bytes
Total transferred file size: 0 bytes
Literal data: 0 bytes
Matched data: 0 bytes
File list size: 507
File list generation time: 0.001 seconds
File list transfer time: 0.000 seconds
Total bytes sent: 586
Total bytes received: 78
total size is 5.22M  speedup is 7862.54 (DRY RUN)


[3]
RsyncCommand: 0
Number of files: 54
Number of files transferred: 0
Total file size: 63.67M bytes
Total transferred file size: 0 bytes
Literal data: 0 bytes
Matched data: 0 bytes
File list size: 1.56K
File list generation time: 0.002 seconds
File list transfer time: 0.000 seconds
Total bytes sent: 1.75K
Total bytes received: 185
total size is 63.67M  speedup is 32988.24 (DRY RUN)
```

I want output if I grep 2

```
[2]
RsyncCommand: 0
Number of files: 21
Number of files transferred: 0
Total file size: 5.22M bytes
Total transferred file size: 0 bytes
Literal data: 0 bytes
Matched data: 0 bytes
File list size: 507
File list generation time: 0.001 seconds
File list transfer time: 0.000 seconds
Total bytes sent: 586
Total bytes received: 78
total size is 5.22M  speedup is 7862.54 (DRY RUN)
```

How to use grep command to show below output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use grep with `-A`. Something like:

```
$ grep -A 13 '^\[2\]' inputfile.txt
```

The `-A` specifies the number of lines you want to include after the match.

But I think it would be better to use `sed` in this case:

```
$ sed -n '/^\[2\]/,/^$/p' inputfile.txt
```

This will print everything between `[2]` and an empty line.

The same using `awk`:

```
$ awk -v RS='' -v ORS='\n\n' '/^\[2\]/' inputfile.txt
```

Comment: The thing I missed most when moving away from AIX was the `grep -p` option.  Outputs the paragraph which includes the match (and you can tell it what paragraph separator to use).  Someone should add that to GNU grep.

Comment: There is already an open feature request for that: http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?14630

Comment: And what to do if I want to grep Total file size: after [2] and before [3] means between [2] and [3]

Comment: There are multiple ways to achieve this with `sed`. The simplest way based on my example: `sed -n '/^\[2\]/,/^$/{/^Total file size:/p}' inputfile.txt`

Comment: Your sed commands output show me [2] and [3] both's output

Comment: That's weird. It works for me. Try for example with `sed -n '/^\[2\]/,/^\[3\]/{/^Total file size:/p}' inputfile.txt`.